# does pandas reduce the run time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

I have a code written with python which contains different matrix and for loops to change the matrix elements. But it takes a lot of time to run. Now the question is if I change the matrices to pandas DataFrames and series does is decrease the run time?

Comment: Numpy would faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick to nested for loops, your code will per se not benefit from putting the data into pandas or numpy datastructures. Btw. how is this solved now?. But both numpy and pandas are optimized for vectorized operations and this will decrease the run time significantly. However, you will need to adjust you coding style, see e.g. [A Beginner’s Guide to Optimizing Pandas Code for Speed](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

If this doesn't answer your question, consider this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)